# Decode a WCDMA signal

Tags: signal, matlab, telecommunications

I am trying to decode a WCDMA signal on MATLAB and I am having some trouble trying to grasp the concept of it and was hoping for some feedback.

I have a row vector, 'scrambleCode,' containing 38400 elements, which are either '1' or '-1.' This vector was already defined for me, and to get the spread message, I created a new vector called 'spreadMsg,' where:

if scrambleCode(i) is equal to '1', then spreadMsg(i) = 1. and
if scrambleCode(i) is equal to '-1', then spreadMsg(i) = 0.

I have also been given the transmitted signal, a 1420800 element row vector. This row vector consists of elements valued in the range of -0.92 to 0.92.

I have been informed that this signal has 'n' blocks, each of 38400 chips, and that the chip scrambling code is the real part of the 512 primary downlink scrambling codes.

With regards to the 'spreadMsg' vector that I created, is it correct that this is the signal of a user after the users data has been 'x-ored' with the spreading code?

And as for the transmitted signal, how come the signal does not consist of integers? I am assuming that the transmitted signal is the signal that contains the signal of all the users (ie. the addition of each users corresponding 'scrambleCode'), so how come the elements of the transmitted signal are instead decimal values?

I appreciate any guidance. Thank you :-)

Comment: My guess : The transmitted signal is shown to be in decimal to indicate that the perfect `1` and `-1` logic levels are getting corrupted by noise (which included other user's signals) and that the spreading allows even such a degraded signal to be *un-spread* back into the original signal correctly.

Comment: "*if scrambleCode(i) is equal to '1', then spreadMsg(i) = 1. and if scrambleCode(i) is equal to '-1', then spreadMsg(i) = 0.*" Is `spread message` the message *after* spreading ? But you do not show how the original message and the scrabmle code are *mixed* together to get this spread message. Is there something missing in this sentence? Your mention of `xor` in the later paragraph leads me to think that the above sentnece is incomplete.

Comment: Hi AJN, My apologies. I have not been given the original message. I only have the scrambling code consisting of a long vector with 1's and -1's, and a transmitted signal. From the scrambling code consisting of the -1's and 1's, I wanted to get back to the spread message by using the "if scrambleCode(i) is equal to '1', then spreadMsg(i) = 1. and if scrambleCode(i) is equal to '-1', then spreadMsg(i) = 0." My train of thought is that this spread message is the result from "x-oring" the original message with the users spreading code, neither of which I have.

Comment: Also thank you for that. I never even considered that the signal may be getting corrupted!  I will look into it more. Thanks :)

Comment: If you are talking about `xor`ing, I expected four `if`s in your sentence corresponding to 4 entries in the truth table of an `xor` gate. I see only two `if`s. That confuses me.